# How can I save a picture on screen from a button in flutter app

Tags: image, flutter, save, gallery

I am new to Flutter. I want to save a picture displayed on the screen in the gallery by using an icon button. I just want when somebody clicks on the button picture is saved in the gallery. How I can do that?

Comment: Do you want to capture the picture or do you want to download it?

Comment: Download the picture

Answer (score 0):

Use [this package](https://pub.dev/packages/image_gallery_saver) to solve the problem.

or you can try [this also](https://pub.dev/packages/gallery_saver).

Answer (score 0):

you can use `image_gallery_saver`.

1. Add to your dependencies:

   dependencies:
   image_gallery_saver: '^1.7.1'
2. Ask for storage permission to save an image to the gallery.

   <application android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" .....>

Example saving images:

```
_save() async {
   var response = await Dio().get(
           "https://ss0.baidu.com/94o3dSag_xI4khGko9WTAnF6hhy/image/h%3D300/sign=a62e824376d98d1069d40a31113eb807/838ba61ea8d3fd1fc9c7b6853a4e251f94ca5f46.jpg",
           options: Options(responseType: ResponseType.bytes));
   final result = await ImageGallerySaver.saveImage(
           Uint8List.fromList(response.data),
           quality: 60,
           name: "hello");
   print(result);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
GallerySaver.saveImage(image.path);
```

Using the gallery_saver dependency from pub.dev

Link: https://pub.dev/packages/gallery_saver